# Java Regex matcher showing unexpected results

Tags: java, regex, parsing, pattern-matching, ping

I was trying to use Regex to parse data out from the output collected by the standard ping command. However some patterns do not work as expected, even after checking the regex expression in online regex checkers (they work fine in the browser).

The Error I received was as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
    at RegexMatches.parseGroupBytes(RegexMatches.java:77)
    at RegexMatches.main(RegexMatches.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Given that I lack experience with Regex, I would like to know how do proceed in order to fix the problem. The class I used is as below:

```
public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        String input = "[1463895254]PING www.andi.dz (213.179.181.44) 100(128) bytes of data.[1463895254]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=195 ms[1463895255]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=202 ms[1463895256]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=180 ms[1463895257]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=200 ms[1463895258]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=206 ms[1463895259]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=188 ms[1463895260]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=7 ttl=54 time=182 ms[1463895261]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=8 ttl=54 time=223 ms[1463895263]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=9 ttl=54 time=187 ms[1463895263]108 bytes from 213.179.181.44: icmp_seq=10 ttl=54 time=199 ms";
        String input2 = "[1463895327]PING www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24) 100(128) bytes of data.[1463895327]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=868 ms[1463895328]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=2 ttl=110 time=892 ms[1463895329]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=3 ttl=110 time=814 ms[1463895330]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=4 ttl=110 time=1009 ms[1463895331]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=5 ttl=110 time=1006 ms[1463895332]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=6 ttl=110 time=984 ms[1463895333]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=7 ttl=110 time=1004 ms[1463895334]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=8 ttl=110 time=1006 ms[1463895335]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=9 ttl=110 time=1013 ms[1463895336]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=10 ttl=110 time=578 ms[1463895336][1463895336]--- www.gov.bw ping statistics ---[1463895336]10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9007ms[1463895336]rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 578.263/917.875/1013.707/132.095 ms, pipe 2\n";
//        System.out.println(parse1(input));
        try{
            String op[] = parseGroupBytes(input);
            System.out.println(op[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String parse1(String input){
        Pattern p =Pattern.compile("\\[([0-9]{10})\\]PING");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        if (m.find())
            return m.group(1);
        else
            return "error";
    }

// Doesn't Work...
    // patterns seem to be correct but only shows the first value

    public static String[] parseGroupBytes(String input) throws BytesNotFoundException {
        //  Capture the bytes after (ip-address) outside the parenthesis
        //  Capture the bytes after (ip-address) inside the parenthesis
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\)\\s+(\\d+)\\(");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(input);
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)\\s+bytes");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(input);
        String[] GroupBytes = new String[2];
        int x = m1.groupCount();
        int y = m2.groupCount();
        if(m1.find() || m2.find()){
            GroupBytes[0] = m1.group(1);
            GroupBytes[1] = m2.group(1);
              return GroupBytes;
        }
        else
            throw new BytesNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(m1.find() || m2.find()){`  - I think `m1` found a match and `m2` did not really execute as it is after `||`. Run both before the `if`, assign to bool variables, and that should work.

Comment: Why are you breaking the operation into two separate matches?  Just search for `"\\)\\s+(\\d+)\\((\\d+)\\)\\s+bytes"` and extract `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is this block:

```
if(m1.find() || m2.find()){
    GroupBytes[0] = m1.group(1);
    GroupBytes[1] = m2.group(1);
    return GroupBytes;
}
```

Since you're entering in `if` condition if any of the matches succeed for matchers `m1` or `m2` but while executing `m2.group(1)` it will throw `IllegalStateException` **since `m2.find()` never gets executed** due to `||` and `m1.find()` returning true.

Change that block to use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if(m1.find() && m2.find()){
    GroupBytes[0] = m1.group(1);
    GroupBytes[1] = m2.group(1);
    return GroupBytes;
}
else
    throw new BytesNotFoundException();
```

Now code will execute `find()` for both matchers `m1` and `m2` before calling `.group(1)` for each matcher objects.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes you're absolutely correct about what you said but i think I didn't mention the problem clearly enough. I used || instead of && on purpose(temporarily) to isolate the real problem. My problem is getting no matches at runtime while I do get what I want from regex checkers online.

Comment: Code you provided is working fine after replacing `||` by `&&`. Further if you update your code that reproduces your problem then I can investigate and suggest

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `m1.find() || m2.find()` so if m1 finds a match m2 won't be tried so you should change it e.g. to two if checks or merge the regex into a single pattern.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This was intentional to isolate the main problem which is having no matches at runtime, while online regex checkers tell me the pattern is correct

Answer (score 0):

> public String group(int group)

Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the previous match operation.

Problem is that you don't call find on m2 matcher... try this instead

```
m1.find() | m2.find()
```

The fact that you evaluated `matches()` as false at runtime is because `find()` tries to find a subsequence of your input that matches the pattern whereas `matches()` evaluates the whole input. if you want your example to work with `matches()` then you should change the pattern as

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^.*\\)\\s+(\\d+)\\(.*$");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(input);
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^.*\\((\\d+)\\)\\s+bytes.*$");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(input);
...
if(m1.matches() && m2.matches())
//then store values of each matcher group.
```

You can even regroup the 2 patterns into 1 single pattern, bounding both expressions p1 and p2 with an AND condition...

```
 Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(?=^.*\\)\\s+(\\d+)\\(.*$)(?=^.*\\((\\d+)\\)\\s+bytes.*$).*$");
```

Hope this would help you mate :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. This was intentional to isolate the main problem which is having no matches at runtime, while online regex checkers tell me the pattern is correct

Comment: I have edited the answer for you... I hope that's the answer to your actual problem :)

Comment: Sorry but this returns null values